# When turned Airplane mode ON in Iphone and connected to wifi. Iphone shows airplane mode is OFF in flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, airplane-mode

I am using **airplane_mode_checker: ^1.0.2** to determine if airplane mode is turned on or not.

When I am turning airplane mode on, and no wifi is connected so it shows that airplane mode is ON.

But when I connects t any wifi, when airplane mode is ON, it starts showing that airplane mode is OFF. But in settings of my iphone device it shows that airplane mode is ON.

I am not able to figure it out. what's the problem and why it shows airplane mode OFF. when I connect to wifi.

Please help